# Sightly: Iterating over a list and using its index to print another list (not nested, just sharing the index)

Tags: html, list, aem, sightly, htl

I have 2 lists in sightly. list1 and pathList inside object allList

```
<div data-sly-list.list1="${allList.list1}">
    <img src="soemthing">
    <a href="XXXXXXXXX">${list1}</a>
</div>
```

At the place where I had written **"XXXXXXXXX"**, I need to place soemthing like

> ${pathList['list1List.index']}

OR

> ${allList.pathList['list1List.index']}

***So, basically I want to iterate the second list using the index of the first, and I cannot use nested loop.***

But whenever I am trying to use the syntax I mentioned above, I get template parse error because the syntax is wrong. Somebody please guide me as to how to achieve this.

Comment: If you use the list1List.index with ' ', you are using the String "list1List.index". Have you tried with ${allList.pathList[list1List.index]} ?

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: i got the chance to try it out today, and it worked flawlessly. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the index without the ' ', like this: `${allList.pathList[list1List.index]}`

Example:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class TestModel {

    @Inject
    Resource resource;

    private String[] abc = {"a", "b", "c"};
    private String[] def = {"d", "e", "f"};
    ...
}
```

HTL:

```
<sly data-sly-list.first="${model.abc}">
    <p>Test: ${first}  -  ${model.def[firstList.index]}</p>
</sly>
```

Output HTML:

```
<p>Test: a  -  d</p>
<p>Test: b  -  e</p>
<p>Test: c  -  f</p>
```